# DISTINCT columns from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with similar information. Let's call them `DAILYROWDATA` and `SUMMARYDATA`.

Table `DAILYROWDATA`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT
A1   ARIA   BB
A2   CHLOE  BB
A3   RYAN   BB
A4   STEVE  BB
```

Table `SUMMARYDATA`

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT  STATUSIN                STATUSOUT
A1   ARIA   BB          1/21/2020  8:06:23 AM   1/21/2020  8:07:53 AM
A2   CHLOE  BB          1/21/2020  8:16:07 AM   1/21/2020  9:51:21 AM
A1   ARIA   BB          1/22/2020  9:06:23 AM   1/22/2020  10:07:53 AM
A2   CHLOE  BB          1/22/2020  9:16:07 AM   1/22/2020  10:51:21 AM
A3   RYAN   BB          1/22/2020  8:15:03 AM   1/22/2020  9:12:03 AM
```

And I need to combine these two tables and show all data in table `DAILYROWDATA` and set the value if `STATUSIN` = NULL and `STATUSOUT`= Null then write 'NA'. This is the output that I meant:

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT  STATUSIN                STATUSOUT
A1   ARIA   BB          1/21/2020  8:06:23 AM   1/21/2020  8:07:53 AM
A2   CHLOE  BB          1/21/2020  8:16:07 AM   1/21/2020  9:51:21 AM
A3   RYAN   BB          NA                      NA
A4   STEVE  BB          NA                      NA
A1   ARIA   BB          1/22/2020  9:06:23 AM   1/22/2020  10:07:53 AM
A2   CHLOE  BB          1/22/2020  9:16:07 AM   1/22/2020  10:51:21 AM
A3   RYAN   BB          1/22/2020  8:15:03 AM   1/22/2020  9:12:03 AM
A4   STEVE  BB          NA                      NA
```

I need to add some condition, so, i wanna set the value `STATUSIN = NULL` just when there is no `NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT` in one date.. so, that's can be multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` to bring the two tables together.  The trickier part is that you need strings in order to represent the `'NA'`:

```
select drd.*,
       coalesce(cast(statusin as varchar(255)), 'NA') as statusin,
       coalesce(cast(statusout as varchar(255)), 'NA') as statusout
from DAILYROWDATA drd left join
     SUMMARYDATA sd
     on drd.nip = sd.nip;
```

Comment: but, i need some additional condition.. so, i wanna set the value `STATUSIN` = NULL just when there is no `NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT` in one date.. so, that's can be multiple

Comment: Please check my updated question an look at the sample data table